# Override property value from multiple spring active profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I have a spring boot application that has application.yml.

Contents of application.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: default,private
integrations:
  ecom:
    api-url: http://localhost:8080/com
```

Contents of application-private.yml:

```
integrations:
  ecom:
    api-url: http://testenv:8080/com
```

As per my understanding, integrations:ecom:api-url are getting loaded from application-private.yml even though the default profile also has same property.

If two profiles are active, will the property be loaded and used in the order the profiles were specified?

My order:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="default,private"
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This seems like something that would be pretty simple for you to test and find out. Is something happening that leads you to believe they are read in that order?

Comment: why don't you give it a try....

Comment: To be more clear remove the property from application.yml. If it is profile specific one, why don't put it in application-{profile}.yml only?

Comment: I given a try and tested it. property is getting loaded from application-private.yml. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

For your example, the following is the order of precedence in which Spring will get the value of the property (highest to lowest priority):

1. `application-private.yml` provided *outside* your jar file (for example, via spring-cloud-config)
2. `application.yml` provided *outside* your jar file (application.yml is equivalent to application-default.yml)
3. `application-private.yml` provided *inside* your jar file
4. `application.yml` provided *inside* your jar file

So, if you have application-private.yml and application.yml inside the jar file, properties in the former override properties in the latter.

However, if application-private.yml is inside the jar but application.yml is outside, the latter will override the former.

See [official documentation about external property precedence.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, all properties in ***application.yml*** will be loaded first and then ***application-private.yml*** will be loaded based on the profile, hence overriding your property from ***application.yml***

Comment: Actually, it depends on whether the yml files are loaded from inside or outside the boot app jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, configuration files will be loaded as per the series how you determine/define the profiles. Here is how it works with example:

1. You have application.yml and you have defined your url as: "https://anish.com" Now from same YML configuration, you are loading profile as "prod", so it tries to load "application-prod.yml".
2. In your "application-prod.yml" file, you have your url mentioned as "https://panthi.com", then in this case, your url value will be overridden by "https://panthi.com".

So, make sure you are trying to match the URLs based on the environment that you want to deploy. If you are loading multiple profiles in production, then make sure that the last profile has everything that you need or you make sure you are not overriding any properties in any of the profiles (unless required)